# integrate digital persona sdk into my application in java

Tags: java, sdk, fingerprint

I need urgent help, after googling a lot since last 3-4 weeks. I only able to figure out that, i can use digital persona sdk on my web application, which i am trying to make in java.

Since, hardware for **fingerprint reader (Digital Persona Personal)** has already been installed in my system. And, i'm trying to use same hardware for my web application. But, how can i embed it in my application, don't know.

I'm assuming that, fingerprint reader (Digital Persona Personal) will be installed in client side.

I need everyone help, anybody know.. i'll appreciate !!

Comment: There is someone telling about here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690698/applet-with-fingerprint-uareu-dont-capture-reader-events

Comment: Please don't add not working link @user984453

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, what you want to achieve can be a bit hard to do depending on your needs/experience, but having done a biometric matching/enrollment/digital signature system in delphi(client)/java(server) i can summarize the steps as follows:

1.- The client is an win32 activex (could be a java applet) that can take a fingerprint image and send it to the server for matching or enrollment purposes, the server takes the image and applies a matching function that returns a score, here i recommend you to take a look at some paid options like verifinger, griaule etc. I dont know if it can be done with the UareU One Touch SDK.

2.- The client is an Activex embedded in the web page as an object (calling an applet is very similar), you just call it with a simple javascript code like "identResult = activexObj.Identify()" or something. The image is sent to the server which in return replies if the fingerprint matches the template stored, comparing the score vs threshold defined as the minimum for matching.

3.- Probably you will need to do some image processing in the client, like converting your raw image to a compressed format like WSQ, there are no (to my knowledge) java implementations of wsq, so you will have to interface to native code via JNI for this purpose.

4.- There might be a lot of nuances but i hope this helps you to clarify the situation.
Good Luck
Juan.

Answer (score 0):

```
switch (irq_type) {
    case IRQDATA_SCANPWR_ON:
        updateStatus(Status.SCANNER_POWERED_ON);
        reader.awaitFinger();
        updateStatus(Status.READY_TO_SCAN);
        break;
    case IRQDATA_FINGER_ON:
        updateStatus(Status.FINGER_DETECTED);
        UruImage img = reader.captureFinger(data_endpoint);
        sendImage(img);
        break;
    case IRQDATA_FINGER_OFF:
        updateStatus(Status.FINGER_LIFTED);
        reader.turnScannerOff();
        updateStatus(Status.SCANNER_POWERED_OFF);
        listen = false;
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

try this android app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.digitalpersona.digitalpersona

for more info:
http://digital.persona.sdk.android.brainwaveappstudio.com/